# How to remove www before the IP address

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, ip

I am redirecting my website from non www to www using htaccess,

**.htaccess file config**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So that my domain is redirecting to `www.website.com` instead of `website.com` .

But the problem comes when i access the website using IP address, It is adding `www` to the IP address like this `http://www.192.168.0.0/` . How remove the www before IP?

**DNS**

```
 A        @       <IP> 

CNAME     *       <www.website.com>
```

Comment: I think this is an artifact of the browser you are using.  Instead of typing in "192.168.0.0" into the location bar, try typing in "http://192.168.0.0/" and see if the browser then still appends "www" to the front of the address.

Comment: @shooper it's because he's using the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable in the rule. It takes the host that is requested.

Comment: @shooper, I have tried that method too, But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this htaccess rule is only used for one site you can just use the domain name instead of the variable. Like this below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition to make sure this `www` doesn't happen for IP address:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\d{1,3\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to fix but very little. You should specify your mod rewrite differently in this case; you might want to integrate {HTTP_HOST} for domain name detection; if this applies for one domain, I'd leave it and try it as is.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This will not redirect IP addresses.